# Making pivot items visible from a fixed range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a table in Sheet "Code". In column C i have some country code like DE,FR,GB...I just want to select all the values and make at as visible in pivot table which is available in the Main sheet. I used the code below but not working and not showing error. Help me to change my code.

```
Sub pivot()
Dim wst,ws As Worksheet
Dim arr1() As String
Dim j As Long

Set wst = Sheets("Code")
LastCol = wst.Cells(wst.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim Preserve arr1(1 To LastCol)
  For j = 1 To LastCol
     arr1(j) = wst.Cells(j, 3).Value
Next j

Set ws = Worksheets("Main")    
 ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code").ClearAllFilters
    With ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code")
      For Each pi In .PivotItems
        pi.Visible = InStr(1, arr1, pi.Name) > 0
      Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you can't compare an entire array `arr1` using `InStr`, you need to decide which element you want to compare, like `arr1(1)`, or `arr1(j)`. If you want to see whether `pi.Name` is found within the entire array, you can use `Application.Match(pi.Name, arr1, 0)`

Comment: Also, where are you defining and setting the `ws` worksheet object ?

Comment: @ShaiRado now i changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Shai beat me to the punch on this. I have assumed  Set ws = Sheets("Main")

```
Option Explicit

Sub pivot()

    Dim wst As Worksheet
    Dim arr1() As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Main")
    Set wst = Sheets("Code")
    lastRow = wst.Cells(wst.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim Preserve arr1(1 To lastRow)

    For j = 1 To lastRow
        arr1(j) = wst.Cells(j, 3).Value
    Next j

    Worksheets("Main").PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code").ClearAllFilters
    Dim Pi As PivotItem

    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Set pvt = ws.PivotTables("MainTable")

    With pvt.PivotFields("Country Code")

        For Each Pi In .PivotItems
            If IsError(Application.Match(Pi.Name, arr1, 0)) Then Pi.Visible = False
        Next Pi

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: naughty naughty ;) , however, you don't need to use the `Pi.Visible = True` section, since you already used `ClearAllFilters` a few lines before, so you don't need to make the items visible again. Just look when `IsError` to hide these items

Comment: Feel free to post your answer and I will happily delete. I was still typing. Appreciate the correction though!

Comment: No, i'm not typing this whole thing ;) my kids are "riding" me, so that won't be happening